# Set radio button list from vb code behind

Tags: vb.net, vba, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list.  When the page is loaded I have some scripts and other things that run to determine if an ID has passed or failed a test.  So what I am trying to actually do is when that page loads set my radio button to  fail after the script runs

Here is the list:

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="rblInspectionStatus" CssClass="descbold"  runat="server" repeatColumns="2" repeatDirection="Horizontal">
       <asp:listitem Value="Pass">Pass</asp:listitem>
       <asp:listitem Value="Fail">Fail</asp:listitem>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

What I have tried is:

```
rblInspectionStatus.Items.FindByValue("Fail").Selected = True 
rblInspectionStatus.Items.FindByText("Fail").Selected = True
rblInspectionStatus.SelectedIndex |SelectedItem | SelectedValue
```

Comment: Copy/paste of `rblInspectionStatus.Items.FindByValue("Fail").Selected = True` works fine for me.  Either the sub this code is in is not running, or something is running after it that is overriding it.

Comment: I agree with @TonyHinkle - Is the RadioButtonList in an ItemTemplate, in say a Repeater Control or something similar?

Comment: @TonyHinkle this actually was correct.  I thought this the sub that contained the code to set the radio button was last but to my surprise it was not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do in that `Sub` or as User Tony Hinkle and User NoAlias are trying to say is correct but this is my assumption:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            cn.Open() 'Opens the connection
            cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT PF FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '" & Session("ID") & "'", cn)
            drr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If drr.Read Then
                rblInspectionStatus.ClearSelection()
                rblInspectionStatus.Items.FindByValue(drr.Items("PF")).Selected = True
            'FIELD PF data either Pass or Fail
            ElseIf Not drr.Read Then
                rblInspectionStatus.ClearSelection()
                rblInspectionStatus.SelectedIndex = -1
            End If
            cn.Close() 'Close the connection
        End Sub
```